# Partition array based on pivot

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, pivot, quicksort

I wrote a simple implementation to partition array based on pivot. For simplicity, the first element in the array is taken as the pivot element. Below is the code I wrote

```
public static void partitionOnPivot(int[] a , int lo , int hi)
{

    int pivot = lo;

    while (lo < hi)
    {
        while(a[lo] <= a[pivot]) lo++;
        while(a[hi] > a[pivot]) hi--;

        if(lo < hi) //we are already done with these cases
        {
            ArrayUtil.swap(a, lo++, hi--);
        }
    }

    ArrayUtil.swap(a, pivot, lo);

}
```

Now for the below array,

```
{26,84,98,45}
```

at one point, both `lo` and `hi` will stand at index 1.

At this point 26 is swapped with 84 and the output becomes `{84, 26, 98, 45}`. 26 should have been left alone.

I have been making some changes for quite a long time with no progress.  How do we handle this corner case? Is there any bug in the program ?

Answer (score 0):

use this statement at the end of outer while loop

```
ArrayUtil.swap(a, pivot, hi);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayUtil.swap(a, lo++, hi--);` is where your undesired behaviour is creeping in, I'll bet.  Because `++` is postincrement, you are swapping the high element with your pivot, then incrementing the pivot.

Comment: sorry, I'm going mad - discount my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"at one point, both lo and hi will stand at index 1" -> WRONG
From the program you have written it is clear that lo will be at index 1 while hi will be at index 0 . So the following if condition will be skipped and the last line swapping the values at the two indexes will be executed

```
  if(lo < hi) //THE FOLLOWING STATEMENT WILL BE SKIPPED
   {
        ArrayUtil.swap(a, lo++, hi--);
   }
```

The resulting array would be {84, 26, 98, 45}. which is exactly what you are getting. You should make the following changes

```
while(a[lo] <= a[pivot]) lo++;
while(a[hi] > a[pivot]) hi--;
```

becomes

```
while(a[lo + 1] <= a[pivot]) lo++;
while(a[hi - 1] > a[pivot]) hi--;
```

Also as others have pointed out try changing

```
ArrayUtil.swap(a, lo++, hi--);
```

to

```
ArrayUtil.swap(a, lo, hi);
```

P.S I think increment and decrement operators are evil. One has to really pay attention about the post/pre behavior when using them. Try to avoid them as much as you can.

Comment: Why does while(a[hi] > a[pivot]) hi--;  become while(a[hi - 1] > a[pivot]) hi-- ? What if a[hi] < pivot, you might end up ignoring that.

Comment: Also, regarding the increment and decrement operators, I knew what I was doing; Swap then increment and decrement, not the other way around.

Comment: I've edited my original answer, there was a mistake in there, sorry for that. As for the conidition that a[hi] < pivot, this condition will be convered by the if condition checking if(lo < hi) and will be handled appropriately. And yes regarding the increment and decrement operators i had the wrong impression about what you were trying to achieve, again sorry for that. But i think still they are bad :)

Comment: I am not sure If I understand your a[hi] < pivot comment. For example, for the input {26,84,98,21}, the output is 26, 84, 98, 21,

Comment: what if a[hi] <= a[pivot] in the beginning it self?

Comment: @user2434 your entire code is fine. just change your last line as I answered above.

Comment: Ok, you are right again and i am wrong (i think i need to have some coffee). I gave your program a long, hard look and here is my suggestion. The program breaks out of the outer while loop when lo > hi (lo == hi will not occur after the loop ends). So lo will be in the region of numbers greater than the pivot and hi will be in the region of numbers less than or equal to the pivot so the statement at the end of your program should be ArrayUtil.swap(a, pivot, --lo);